# PHP redirect with POST

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, post, redirect

Ok so i am trying to do a redirect with PHP with a PaymentID ...i am not sure how to do this ...here are the instructions and even some example asp.net code to help

Redirect to the Mercury HostedCheckout Page
Mercury HostedCheckout URL: Test URL: https://hc.mercurydev.net/Checkout.aspx

Hidden Fields in HTML Form Post to HostedCheckout

```
Field Name   Description                                                          Required
PaymentID    The unique identifier returned by the InitiatePayment web service.   Yes
```

And here is the sample code in C# for asp.net

Redirect sample code
This is sample code that will redirect the browser to Mercury’s HostedCheckout page. It is server side C# code used in an asp.net click event that creates an html response that will redirect to Mercury.

```
//Set the necessary variables before building html.
string hostedCheckoutURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostedCheckoutURL"]; 
string paymentID = this.txtPaymentID.Text;
//Build an html form post to be sent back to the browser. 
//It will redirect the browser to the Mercury HostedCheckout page. 
Response.Clear(); 
Response.Write("<html><head>"); 
Response.Write("</head><body onload=\"document.frmCheckout.submit()\">"); 
Response.Write("<form name=\"frmCheckout\" method=\"Post\" action=\"" + hostedCheckoutURL + "\" >"); 
Response.Write("<input name=\"PaymentID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + paymentID + "\">"); 
Response.Write("</form>"); 
Response.Write("</body></html>"); 
Response.End();
```

Basically I need to do the same request in PHP...any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `include("config.php");` or such to get $hostedCheckoutURL, but I don't know from where do you get PaymentID.

```
<?php
//Set the necessary variables before building html.
$hostedCheckoutURL = "https://hc.mercurydev.net/Checkout.aspx"; 
$paymentID = "123456789";
//Build an html form post to be sent back to the browser. 
//It will redirect the browser to the Mercury HostedCheckout page. 
echo("<html><head>"); 
echo("</head><body onload=\"document.frmCheckout.submit()\">"); 
echo("<form name=\"frmCheckout\" method=\"Post\" action=\"".$hostedCheckoutURL."\" >"); 
echo("<input name=\"PaymentID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$paymentID."\">"); 
echo("</form>"); 
echo("</body></html>");
?>
```

Comment: I have the paymentID....does this request create a form or does it redirect...I thought i had to redirect...thanks again

Comment: nevermind this worked perfectly...thanks but what is this doing....is it writing the form or redirecting and if its redirecting how

Comment: `this.txtPaymentID.Text` I don't know what is this and how you set it, it is being redirected to URL you set in `$hostedCheckoutURL`, I'll edit the answer to make it more clearer.

Comment: I see now...I am writing the form via php and then with the onload automatically submiting to the url set in the config with the paymentID post data